# Multiple paths in php define

Tags: php, path, constants

So, this is how I connect css, for example.

```
define( 'SCRIPT_ROOT','http://localhost/projects/name/assets');
```

And then :

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'.SCRIPT_ROOT.'/css/reset.css">';
```

It works just fine, but when I upload my project to server - everything goes wrong.

So, the question is - how can I define multiple paths in this case and is that even possible?

Comment: Why the `http://localhost`? Would probably be much easier to just use the web root.

Answer (score 2):

The value for `SCRIPT_ROOT` is wrong in production because it is different than your development environment. You need to either change it or have separate files for each location that allow you to have separate values.

An alternative and simpler solution is to use a relative path  from your root web directory instead of a full URL:

```
// path from the root web directory
define( 'SCRIPT_ROOT','/projects/name/assets');
```